# Adding class as file to Xcode 4

Tags: xcode

I have a .h and .m files on my computer and want to add them to my xCode project.
I right click on the Classes folder and selects "Add files".
The files get copied, but they wont show up in the xCode view?
How do i get them to show up under my classes folder?

Cheers Johan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select both files and drag them over to the Project navigation view, drop them in the desired location and then a Dialog will appear under you need to make sure you have the "Copy files to destination.. (if needed)" check-box checked.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems adding files with the same name as files I'd deleted.
Try changing the filename slightly and see if it will add them.